# Difficulties with adding arrows to plot in R

Tags: r, plot, arrows

I am attempting to project data onto a plot in R and see the correlation between the points. I have added a line to let the reader see the connection between these points. I am however stumped when it comes to inputting arrows to show the direction of the line. Rddproj was just an arbitrary name given to the data. Three sets of x and y coordinates are plotted `x=c(-0.7159425, -0.8129311, -0.7392371); y=0.7743088, 0.7732762, 0.7490996)` Here is the example below.

```
x<-rddproj[1:3,1]; y<-rddproj[1:3,2]
plot(x,y)
```

[image: Simple Plot of Data]

My concern is that the second group of coordinates is the greatest negative point on the x-axis. In drawing a line with arrows, the arrow will most likely point towards this point, when it should be forming a V with that point in the middle. Is it possible to plot an arrow to reflect the placement of points in a group and not just the most positive point to the most negative point or vice versa?

Comment: You can customize lines over your plot using  `abline()` after plotting the graph. Not sure what you mean by "forming a V with that point in the middle" but this may be useful.

Comment: I knew about customizing the line but my arrows were being a bit of a struggle. Next time I will word my question a little more clearly. Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrows function ( a modified segments function) is used for this purpose (to the extent that I understand the question) in base R:

```
# fixed your assignment code.
plot(NA, xlim=range(x), ylim=range(y) )
arrows(head(x,-1),head(y,-1),tail(x,-1), tail(y,-1), angle=30)
```

[image]

An alternative reading of your question would have the glaringly obvious solution : `plot(x,y)` which I hope is not what you were asking since that should have been satisfactory.

Comment: Woohoo! This worked perfectly. My issue was that I was sequentially rearranging my results and then attempting to use the arrow function similar to another example. Thank you for the assitance. Have a nice day!